# Manjaro Linux on laptop cannot see SD card

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card, fdisk, manjaro

The `dmesg` output:

```
[ 9376.684650] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[ 9378.738987] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[ 9378.859232] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 59b4
```

`lsblk` and `fdisk -l` does not show any **new** disks.
The KDE Partition Manager does not see it too.

I tried to find it in `/dev` but with no success:

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb4
/dev/sg0
/dev/sg1
/dev/snapshot
/dev/stderr
/dev/stdin
/dev/stdout
```

Nothing of them is sdcard. The list is the same when SD card inserted and ejected.

#### update

`lspci` output (shortened):

```
$ lspci
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

**Unassigned class.** Does this mean system needs driver for **RTL8411B**?

#### update 2. Solved semi-accidentally.

For a few hours I was digging the internet and found package which should install

> A kernel module for Realtek Card Reader RTL8402/8411/8411B Device

It is named `rts_bpp-dkms-git`

```
~ ❯❯❯ yaourt rts_bpp-dkms-git
1 aur/rts_bpp-dkms-git 6-1 [installed: 7-1] (1) (0,00)
    A kernel module for Realtek Card Reader RTL8402/8411/8411B Device
==> Enter n° of packages to be installed (e.g., 1 2 3 or 1-3)
==> ---------------------------------------------------------
==>
```

I tried to install it and met the yet another problem:

```
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Install DKMS modules
==> No kernel 4.9.52-lts headers. You must install them to use DKMS!
```

Seems package was installed but with FAIL.
Need to install linux49-headers

```
$ pacman -Ss linux headers
# pacman -S linux49-headers
```

*Note: use `uname -a` to get know the system name and Linux kernel version.*

Than I have got one more thing about *dkms cannot find linux headers fot 4.9.52*. I checked pointed folder with

```
$ ls /usr/lib/modules/
4.9.53-1-MANJARO  extramodules-4.9-MANJARO
```

and found there linux headers version 4.9.53-1. I think that happened because of system was updated with `octopi` (`pacman -Suy`) and was not restarted.

**O, Magic. After system reboot (sd card was inserted all time) Dolphin can see partiotons of SD card. And I have `mmcblk0` device**. Check it with  `lsblk`.

Comment: For future reference, if lsblk does not find your disk, KDE Partition Manager would not find either. KPM uses lsblk --json to find the list of devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem: no driver for RTL8411B

```
$ lspci
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

### Solution find and install driver

But first we need to know: the drivers installed through `dkms` and it usually requires Linux headers.

**First** get know kernel version

```
$ uname -a  
Linux kyb-manjaro-laptop 4.9.53-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 5 15:11:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is `4.9.53-1-MANJARO`

**Second** install Linux headers.

```
$ pacman -Ss linux headers
```

Select your one and install it

```
# pacman -S linux49-headers
```

**Third** install driver itself

```
$ yaourt -S rts_bpp-dkms-git
```

**Last** step - restart the system. Optional, may be your system will work without reboot.

---

P.S. To search drivers for another hardware chip try:

for **Arch Linux** based:

```
yaourt DRIVER_NAME
```

for **Debian, Ubuntu**:

```
apt search DRIVER_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was longgg time figuring out why didn't work all the time under Manjaro. Now is working.

Comment: Yo you totally saved hours of fighting with my computer. Thanks so much!